# Unable to copy files of certain extension in Python using loop

Tags: python-2.7

I want to loop through the files present in Audio_files folder and check if it is raw file or wave file and put it in the respective directories.
Here is my code:

```
import shutil
import os

source = os.listdir("/home/GM/codec_implement/Audio_files/")

destination = "/home/GM/codec_implement/raw_files/"
destination2 = "/home/GM/codec_implement/raw_files/wave_files/"

for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".wav"):
        shutil.copy(files,destination)
    elif files.endswith(".raw"):
        shutil.copy(files,destination)
    else:
        print "Invalid format"
```

Please let me know where I am making mistake. Error i get is:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "./checkaudiofiles.py", line
>   12, in  shutil.copy(files,destination) File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 119, in copy copyfile(src, dst)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile with
>   open(src, 'rb') as fsrc: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'test_sound.wav'

Comment: You haven't told us what problem you are having with this code.

Comment: what is going wrong, or what error is being produced?

Comment: It says that the Directory does not exist: The exact error is:  [GM@GM-HP ~/codec_implement]$ ./checkaudiofiles.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./checkaudiofiles.py", line 12, in <module>
    shutil.copy(files,destination)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 119, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_sound.wav'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that the test_sound.wav file is not on that directory. These file might be removed between the two proces or the `os.listdir()` and the `shutil.copy()` don't list the files the same way.

Comment: The file is there I see it but may be something different is going on that I cant understand. I don't see any issue with the code though.